# Pandas DataFrame to multidimensional array conversion

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying out the Kaggle MNIST competition. The data is provided in a CSV, and I want to convert it to a 28x28 Numpy array. The best way I know to import a CSV data set is via `pd.read_csv()`, but utilizing that, and then a `pd.DataFrame.values()`, provides me with an array that is (42000,784)--which is no problem, as I don't have to flatten it in TensorFlow, but then my test data is compromised for having a similar shape. Is there a way to take the (42000,784) DataFrame and convert it to a (42000,28,28) array?

Comment: Simply reshape to desired shape?

Comment: @Divakar Something to the effect of np.array.reshape(-1,28,28)?

Comment: `df.values.reshape(42000,28,28) ` with `df` being the input dataframe.

Comment: @Divakar Well count me dumb as bricks. Thanks. Easy as apple pie and I didn't even see it.